# Save nested json into database in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, guzzle

I'm consuming an API with Guzzle via laravel and storing the response into a database.

I've been successful in storing the "ratings" part of the JSON response. But now I'd like to add "meta" - "extractDate".

What do I need to change to get this to work?

Below is the JSON API response I'm working from and part of the controller I'm using to save into my database.

Using laravel 7.0

```
**JSON from API**

{
    "ratings": [
        {
            "ratingId": 12,
            "ratingName": "5",
            "ratingKey": "fhrs_5_en-gb",
            "ratingKeyName": "5",
            "schemeTypeId": 1,
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "href": "http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/ratings/12"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "dataSource": "API",
        "extractDate": "2020-06-29T21:24:43.820107+01:00",
        "itemCount": 11,
        "returncode": "OK",
        "totalCount": 11,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "pageSize": 11,
        "pageNumber": 1
    }
}
```

```
**controller snippet**

        $client = $this->client();
        $request = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/ratings');
        $ratings = json_decode($request->getBody()->getContents(), true);

        collect($ratings['ratings'])
            ->each(function($rating, $key) {
                Rating::updateOrCreate([
                    'ratingId' => $rating['ratingId'],
                    'ratingName' => $rating['ratingName'],
                    'ratingKey' => $rating['ratingKey'],
                    'ratingKeyName' => $rating['ratingKeyName'],
                    'schemeTypeId' => $rating['schemeTypeId'],
                    'extractDate' => $rating['extractDate']
                ]);
            });
```

Edit -- Additional Info

Correct me if I'm wrong but at the moment I think the collection is only able to save the contents of the "Ratings" object. I've tried to remove the object from the collect line and amend each line as:

```
 'ratingId' => $rating['rating']['ratingId'],
 'extractDate' => $rating['meta']['extractDate']
```

But I get 'Undefined index: rating'

DD of $ratings

```
array:3 [▼
  "ratings" => array:11 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "ratingId" => 12
      "ratingName" => "5"
      "ratingKey" => "fhrs_5_en-gb"
      "ratingKeyName" => "5"
      "schemeTypeId" => 1
      "links" => array:1 [▶]
    ]
    1 => array:6 [▶]
    2 => array:6 [▶]
    3 => array:6 [▶]
    4 => array:6 [▶]
    5 => array:6 [▶]
    6 => array:6 [▶]
    7 => array:6 [▶]
    8 => array:6 [▶]
    9 => array:6 [▶]
    10 => array:6 [▶]
  ]
  "meta" => array:8 [▼
    "dataSource" => "API"
    "extractDate" => "2020-06-29T22:56:04.250649+01:00"
    "itemCount" => 11
    "returncode" => "OK"
    "totalCount" => 11
    "totalPages" => 1
    "pageSize" => 11
    "pageNumber" => 1
  ]
  "links" => array:1 [▶]
]
```

Comment: You need to post more information. What specifically is not working? Error messages, supporting information, things you have tried.

Comment: Updated @KurtFriars

Comment: How are you populating this $ratings variable?

Comment: $ratings = json_decode($request->getBody()->getContents(), true);

Comment: Can you dd($ratings), also try using a foreach loop instead of collect, if my hunch is correct.

Comment: I've added the DD of ratings above. I'm quite new to php/laravel so I'm unsure of how to change the collect to foreach

Comment: I don't see what the issue would be. Try to dd($rating), inside your collect()->each()

Comment: Nevermind I see it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any data structured like this:

```
'ratingId' => $rating['rating']['ratingId']
```

There is no key in your that is 'rating'.

You have

```
'ratingId' => $ratings['ratings'][$idx]['rating_id']
```

I think what you want is this:

```
collect($ratings['ratings'])
    ->each(function($rating, $key) use ($ratings) {
        Rating::updateOrCreate([
            'ratingId' => $rating['ratingId'],
            'ratingName' => $rating['ratingName'],
            'ratingKey' => $rating['ratingKey'],
            'ratingKeyName' => $rating['ratingKeyName'],
            'schemeTypeId' => $rating['schemeTypeId'],
            'extractDate' => $ratings['meta']['extractDate']
        ]);
    });
```

My original comment is based on your question :)

[image: Question]

Comment: Sorry Kurt I don't follow. With my existing setup, I'm able successfully save all the contents into my database. It's just the ["meta"]["extractDate"] that I can't get to work. I've tried amending to the structure in your first comment but I end up with 'Undefined index: rating' when I try the following: ```'ratingId' => $rating['rating']['ratingId']```

Comment: Your issue is not with meta, the error message is telling you it is with 'rating'

Comment: But I get 'Undefined index: rating'

Comment: I think i have solved your problem, but here is a circumstance where I think foreach is much better than your collect approach, so you dont need to scope in ratings to your closure.

Comment: I am signing off for the day. I hope the final solution I posted worked for you :)